# Adding IPv6 support for JCIFS client

Tags: java, jcifs

I have client written using JCIFS library. Now I need to support IPv6. But JCIFS does not support.

What direction should I take please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are any quick fixes.  (The jCIFS team apparently don't believe that many people want IPv6 support.  That maybe true right now, but surely it will have to change.)

I can suggest a couple of options:

- Request it; e.g. add a "request for enhancement" against jCIFS using the [Samba bugzilla](https://bugzilla.samba.org/).
- Implement it yourself.  [This thread](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/hguzuRIxSoNZd7yjNtqu) might give you some ideas about how to go about it.
- Approach the jCIFS team about **paying someone** to implement it for you.